# Swift unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I know that this question asked many times,but I am not getting hint or answer from those.Actually I am new in swift.I created a viewcontrollerr with subclass of `UITableViewController`.When i click on table row or cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method I am getting this error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.
 I am trying to push viewcontroller.

```
class SideMenuController: UITableViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            break
        case 1:
            let vc = addValueVC(nibName: "addValueVC", bundle: nil)

           //following line is giving error
           self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)

            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: use `?` optional wrapping instead of `!` force, so write like this `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)`

Comment: @NDoc Nothing error,but I am not able to push view controller from this

Comment: Cross check your `self.navigationController`. Is it nil. Do you have navigation controller in current controller.

Comment: In storyboard Embed your `SideMenuController` with `UINavigationController`

Comment: @pkc456 I have not embed this controller in naviagtioncontroller. you are right self.navigationController gives nil

Comment: I am not using storybord ,using from programtically

Comment: So as NDoc stated, embed your controller in navigation controller OR create navigation controller programatically.

Comment: actually,I embed navigation controller in appdelegate with some contoller except this controller.

 let leftMenuViewController = SideMenuController();
let container = MFSideMenuContainerViewController();
        container.centerViewController = tabBarController
        container.leftMenuViewController = leftMenuViewController
        container.rightMenuViewController  = nil
    window?.rootViewController = container

Comment: Which object is nil ?, Try adding an exception breakpoint and check for the object that is nil and mention it.

Comment: @Yatendra, how you show/push `SideMenuController`  (from `tabBarController` )?

Comment: @pkc456 on navigation button click

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using `UINavigationViewController`, you should replace this line

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

with this:

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```